# Google Script: How to Know when someone Login or Logout from Google Spreadsheet and alert me by Email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

## Situation:

I have a spreadsheet with 15 worksheets and 20 users logging in and modifying it.

I want to find a way to send me an email when the user Login & Logout from Spreadsheet.

## Script Function Needed:

1. Send an Email when the user open the spreadsheet.
2. Send an Email when the user logout/logoff/close the spreadsheet.

## Problem:

I don't know how to find the code that told me when the user logout, because I have the following script work for Login but not for logout.

## Test Case:

This script have a trigger when someone open the spreadsheet.

```
    function LoginShift(){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
         MailApp.sendEmail("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "Login Shift" , "Login UserName: " + Session.getEffectiveUser());
      }
```

Is there any way to do the same but for alert me when the user logout?

Comment: As of now, there is now trigger to run when a user closes the spreadsheet. You can request for this feature in the issue tracker

Comment: Srik, do you have any link because I didn't find anything regarding trigger to run when the user closes the spreadsheet.

Comment: What I meant was "You can open an issue in the issue tracker". There is none existing.

Answer (score 0):

"Open" event + menu

There is an open event https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events
and you could add a menu that people can use to send an automated email before they logout.

Re: Srik's comment. A feature request is worth a try, but probably a long shot.